# Using half of a series circuit

Tags: voltage, batteries, battery-charging, series

I have a UPS that has two 12V batteries wired in series. I'd like to pull 12 volts off of one of the batteries to directly run some 12v DC equipment without going through the built in UPS AC inverter and a 12v transformer due to the extra draw those have.

Is it ok to do this? It seems to read 12v when I check these points with a volt meter.

Will this work? Am I going to prematurely fry one battery or over tax the charge circuit in the UPS? Should I just do this with a step-down converter?

Thanks

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkskfv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Don't do that!

The "bottom" battery (V2) will be discharged more than V1 - this will lead to V1 being over-charged, and possibly damaged, by the UPS charger.

Use a 24V -> 12V DC-DC converter to feed your 12 volt loads.